# Highcharts: Set DPi and resolution for scientific papers

Tags: highcharts

I have a web application that creates charts with Highcharts. This works fine for the online display of the data, but I would like to make it possible to download the plot, with specific resolution and size, so that one can use it for scientific publications, where special requirements are necessary.

For example, for almost all publications you need a DPI > 300 and a fixed image width.
Usually the image width should be 90mm/3.54 inch, which results in a pixel count of 1065 for 300 dpi.

Is there any way to set the image size and DPI of the plot?

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't provide any options for customizing DPI of the exported chart, but you can specify the width of the image instead:

```
  exporting: {
    width: 1065
  }
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8cmdc3y6/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.width